# Crop Text within Div (with multiple <p> and <ul>)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text, crop

I want/have to find a solution, where I can crop the contents of a div to a specific character length for a collapse/expand function. The problem is that the text from the RTE (from the cms) consists  of multiple `<p>` tags and basic formatting and lists.

For the demo I have written a hacky function that just strips all the text and puts it in one single paragraph, but this is just a workaround that I need to solve now.

Is there a way to solve this? Sadly I just cant add a new field in the CMS for a teaser text...

html

```
<div class="process-item-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
      <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
let process_showChar = 240;
let process_ellipsestext = "...";
let process_moretext = "+ Expand";
let process_lesstext = "- Collapse";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.process-hidden').first().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 200);
})

$('.process-item-text').each(function () {
    let content = $(this).find('p').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<p>');
    let newText = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        newText += content[i].textContent + "<br>";
    }
    content = newText
    if (content.length > process_showChar) {
        let shortenedContent = content.substr(0, process_showChar);
        let hiddenContent = content.substr(process_showChar, content.length - process_showChar);

        let html = shortenedContent + '<span class="process-moreEllipses">'
            + process_ellipsestext + '</span><span class="process-readmore-content"><span>'
            + hiddenContent + '</span><a href="" class="process-readmore-link">'
            + process_moretext
            + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you put that in fiddle and let us have a look at working demo? Do you want expand/collapse functionality?

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are having here. Can you explain what the current behaviour is vs the desired behaviour?